# WebApi async action filter transactions

Tags: asp.net-web-api, transactionscope

Up till now, we've implemented synchronous WebApi methods. Each action has a transaction created prior to the action call and that transaction is committed at the end of the call if all successful. If I now need to implement an async action, how would I need to change the action filter below to still have the transaction commit correctly? or would I need to implement a DelegatingHandler? Thank you in advance.

```
[AttributeUsage(AttributeTargets.Method, AllowMultiple = false)]
public class TransactionAttribute : ActionFilterAttribute
{
    private IWindsorContainer Container
    {
        get { return IocContainer.Container; }
    }

    private WebRequestContext WebRequestContext
    {
        get
        {
            var webRequestContext = Container.Resolve<WebRequestContext>();
            return webRequestContext;
        }
    }

    private TransactionScope TransactionScope
    {
        get { return WebRequestContext.TransactionScope; }
        set { WebRequestContext.TransactionScope = value; }
    }

    public override void OnActionExecuting(HttpActionContext actionContext)
    {
        var transactionOptions = new TransactionOptions
        {
            IsolationLevel = IsolationLevel.ReadCommitted 
        };
        TransactionScope = new TransactionScope(TransactionScopeOption.Required,
            transactionOptions);

        base.OnActionExecuting(actionContext);
    }

    public override void OnActionExecuted(HttpActionExecutedContext actionExecutedContext)
    {
        using (TransactionScope)
        {
            base.OnActionExecuted(actionExecutedContext);
            if (IsSuccessfulInvocation(actionExecutedContext))
            {
                TransactionScope.Complete();
            }
        }
    }

    private static bool IsSuccessfulInvocation(HttpActionExecutedContext actionExecutedContext)
    {
        return actionExecutedContext.Exception == null;
    }
```